# Partially match integers in PostgreSQL queries

Tags: regex, postgresql, integer

So in my PostgreSQL 10 I have a column of type `integer`. This column represents a code of products and it should be searched against another code or part of the code. The values of the column are made of three parts, a five-digit part and two two-digit parts. Users can search for only the first part, the first-second or first-second-third.

So, in my column I have , say `123451233` the user searches for `12345` (the first part). I want to be able to return the `123451233`. Same goes if the users also searches for `1234512` or `123451233`.

Unfortunately I cannot change the type of column or break the one column into three (one for every part). How can I do this? I cannot use `LIKE`. Maybe something like a regex for integers?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe cast the integer to a string, then regex and LIKE your heart out.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Yeah, I am also leaning to this solution, since I cannot see any other alternative.

Comment: @Adam Hi. No, you have to combine from left to right. So you either search for `part1` or `part1+part2` or `part1+part2+part3` . So, `12345` or `1234512` or `123451233`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need regex functions. Cast the integer to `text` and use the function [`left()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html), example:

```
create table my_table(code int); -- or bigint
insert into my_table values (123451233);

with input_data(input_code) as (
    values('1234512')
)

select t.*
from my_table t
cross join input_data
where left(code::text, length(input_code)) = input_code;

   code    
-----------
 123451233
(1 row)
```

Comment: Very nice solution, but the length inst always gonna be 5. I guess I could get the length of the user input before searching, but still, regex requires no such step.

Comment: Well, `length()` is always cheaper than any regex, see the updated query.

Answer (score 2):

Consider to use simple arithmetic.
`log(value)::int + 1` returns the number of digits in integer part of the `value` and using this:

```
value/(10^(log(value)::int-log(search_input)::int))::int
```

returns `value` truncated to the same digits number as `search_input` so, finally

```
search_input = value/(10^(log(value)::int-log(search_input)::int))::int
```

will make the trick.

It is more complex literally but also could be more efficient then strings manipulations.

PS: **But** having index like `create index idx on your_table(cast(your_column as text));` search like

```
select * from your_table
where cast(your_column as text) like search_input || '%';
```

is the best case IMO.

Comment: The query in PS is optimal if the column is indexed.